# bind Class Property to JSON

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller

How could I combine all class property into a single JSON result in MVC I have the following class properties.

```
public class StudentShortDescription
{ 
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public string age{ get; set; }
}
public class StudentList
{
    public string GuardianName { get; set; }
}

public class accademicdetails
{
    public string acc{get;set;}
}

public class UptoDateAttendance
{
    public decimal Attendancepercentage { get; set; }
}
```

I want to combine all the property to JSON like the following result

```
{
    "Student":[
    {
        "Studentdetails":[{
            "id": "01",
            "name": "abcd",
            "age": "20"         
        }],
        "parents":[{  
            "name":"mothername"
        }],
        "attendance":[{
            "attendance":"70%"
        }]

    }],
    "academic":[{  
        "acc":"2017"
    }]
}
```

how could I get the above response in MVC application?
**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: [Json serialisation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm)

Comment: Just serialize your model class using `Newtonsoft.Json`